# stdin from a file in dev cpp

Tags: c++, stdin, dev-c++

I am looking for a method to input the variables for the code using the content of a file.

More precisely, how I can give very large inputs(containing 10000 of values) from stdin "like we give in online compilers e.g. HACKERRANK".

I have problem in some of the test cases of a problem. The test cases are very large and their(hackerrank's) custom input don't take more than 50Kb.
So if I can get a way to input very large inputs to program in Dev C++ so that I can verify what is wrong in my output(for large values of n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be difficult to enter very large inputs from `stdin`. However you can reopen the `stdin` stream through a file to avoid change in existing code. For example

```
#include <cstdio>

freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);    // redirects standard input

int x;
cin >> x;    // reads from input.txt
```